# Obtener URL de una página en macros de Google

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, url

Estoy necesitando ayuda.
En una página en donde tengo pasado un parámetro desde otra página, no puedo obtener la URL actual de esa página. Intenté con varios métodos, y todos me traen exactamente el mismo valor.

Utilicé:

```
window.location
window.location.href;
document.URL;
$(location).attr('href');
```

Esta es la página (no la van a poder ver, pero es para que vean como está conformada la dirección)

`https://script.google.com/a/macros/x-28.com/s/AKfycbzRilN1OQymn5n1ozMHnOQ8qo7-ezNEBjHwHlSwrm0A/dev?valor=10`

Y esto es lo que obtengo:
`https://n-5cytb36i6dbw3llr5772uymvkkz2irtfz5g2niq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel`

Comment: Retiré [tag:macros] porque en lo que se refiere a [tag:google-apps-script] usualmente se usa `secuencia de comandos` o `script` mientras que [tag:macros] se usa usualmente en para otras plataformas y lenguajes como [tag:c] o [tag:vba]

Answer (score 1):

El obtener el URL de una aplicación web (web app) creada con Google Apps Script resulta complicado, si no es imposible,  usando código del lado del cliente, como es el caso de los ejemplos que mencionas.

El código del lado del servidor a usar sería `ScripApp.getService().getUrl()`

Si además quieres obtener los parámetros, deberás usar el objeto evento obtenido por medio de doGet.

Referencias

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service#geturl
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web